# Crysis crashes on Windows 8 Pro - what to do?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8, crysis, directx-11

I recently got a new PC, which came with Windows 7. I installed Crysis on it and worked just fine. A few days later, Windows 8 was released and I had the option to update  - which I did.

I re-installed all of my games, and they run without any glitches as far as I can tell, all except Crysis. The errors I am getting range from `an error has occurred...` (with a long error code and message that makes no sense to me) to a black window that opens up for a few seconds and then crashes. Similar issues have been reported [on the Steam forums](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=33602131) and on the MyCrisis forums [here](http://www.mycrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=55055) and [here](http://www.mycrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=55852).

I tried running it in compatibility mode with all the older operating system options as suggested in [this post](http://www.mycrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=55055), but no luck, I get the same results.

I also tried patching the game with the latest 1.2 and 1.2.1 patches, it doesn't work either.

How can I get Crysis to work under Windows 8?

Comment: I have tested this on my PC and Crysis is working fine for me, so this is probably something up with your setup - make sure you have the latest drivers installed for Graphics rather than the ones Windows installs as standard, also I noticed when I ran this via Steam that it wanted Punkbuster installing although I doubt a lack of this would cause the symptoms that you're getting. If you are using Steam you could also try to verify the game cache integrity.

Comment: Belatedly, but since this was bumped...I actually recently played through Crysis (on Win7, admittedly) and I can confirm that through Steam you can just cancel the Punkbuster install and the game will work fine.

Comment: Wait until drivers have matured and maybe the game is officially supported by company <xyz>. Until then, I'm voting to close this thread.

Comment: @Bora: While the issue may be related to drivers, support is rapidly increasing for Win8. Also this question was asked after Win8 was released and not during the beta. I believe the reason to close this question is not appropriate: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format." The problem is clear: Crysis doesn't work in Win8 and there are two perfectly good answers that have helped several people. "this question will likely solicit debate" while I agree that different people have different experiences, there is no debate as to what the answer should be.

Comment: @Onema You might want to post about this at [meta] in order to gain more attention about your concern (and possibly, reopen votes).

Comment: @galacticninja thank you for the tip, I just added this: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7089/when-should-be-a-question-consider-as-not-constructive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I appreciate all the useful info you guys have posted there. Here is what worked for me:

1. Un-installed the game completely
2. Install with minimum option (no additional languages, no punkbuster)
3. **By default, the shortcut to the game was using the 64bit version of the game, use the 32bit version instead.**

And Voila!

The game started working again.

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

Try installing DirectX 9.0c.  Some of the older DX9 files that were included in Windows 7 have been removed in Windows 8, and as a result, many games don't work.  You can run the [web installer found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=35) or the [standalone offline installer found here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_directx/).

Comment: What I've heard is that DX10 is fully backwards-compatible but that straight DX9 may be more optimized in some cases; nothing that would completely break a game.

Answer (score 1):

I had Crysis running yesterday, in Windows 7 compatibility mode.  Today I got the same error about the operating system.  The only program I loaded today was Steam.  I opened the task manager, stopped Steam from running then removed it from the start up list.  After I rebooted, Crysis loads and runs just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest hardware drivers? In particular, try updating the driver for the graphics adapter. If that doesn't help, try downloading the reference drivers from ATI or nVidia (depending on the brand of graphics adapter) and see if that helps.

You could also be unfortunate, that you have faulty hardware, e.g. faulty RAM. It is not at all improbable, that running Crysis on Windows 7 would not exercise a faulty piece of RAM, but running it under Windows 8 would. Depending on your RAM configuration in your computer, and your technical expertise, you could try removing a RAM block at a time, and see if it helps with the problem.

Comment: Why would running under Win8 use different parts of RAM that running under Win7 would? The OP said all other games work ok - if it were faulty RAM I'd have expected similar problems with other games...

Comment: I have two or three times experienced faulty RAM, and in the cases I have experienced, the behavior patterns were not at all as random as I would have expected. Typically many different programs would run fine, but one specific program would crash. I'm just saying that if it is possible to remove part of the ram, then it's worth a shot to see if it helps.

Comment: I did have the latest drivers.